# Find if in an array there are at least once all the numbers from 1 to K

Tags: c++, algorithm

Yesterday I did a test on C++ for an interview and I had to find bugs in the following code.

The algorithm takes in input a vector of integer sorted in a non-decreasing order and an integer K. The algorithm returns true if the vector contains only and all the numbers between 1 and k at least once, and false otherwise:

([1,1,2,3,3,4],4) --> true

([1,1,3],3) --> false

This was the implementation:

```
bool algorithm(vector<int> &A, int k)
{
   n = A.size();
   for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
      if(A[i]+1 < A[i+1])
         return false;
   }
   if(A[0] != 1 && A[n-1] != K)
   {
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

I wasn't able to find bug/bugs. Could someone tell me where is/are the bug/s in this code?

Comment: Have you tried creating some test cases and steping through the code using a debugger? It will probably go a long way to help you figure this out and better answer a question like this in the future.

Comment: The debugger is very helpful for finding your issues. Stack Overflow isn't from a long term view.

Comment: Not yet. They give you this without the possibility to use the debugger so probably it's possible to figure it out also without the help of the debugger. I tried to think and reason on it with some other test cases, but I don't see bug/s.

Comment: What does "no-decrescenting" mean?

Comment: Probably I used the wrong term. I meant non-decreasing `i <= i+1`.

Comment: That is usually spelled as 'ascending'. In this case, it is rather easy to see at least first bug. Let's say, you give it a number 4 as K, and the list contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10. It will return false as a result of first loop.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well, but the last element of the vector must be K thus in this case, it's okay that the algorithm returns false, because in the vector must be present only and all the number between 1 and k at least once.

Comment: What test cases have you tried so far? Do they cover all the code branches?

Comment: Probably not. So far I tried different vectors (in length, and with different numbers inside) and different K.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The final check should be an OR as either condition is sufficient reason to return false.  For example, ([0,1,2],2) would pass as the code is now.

Also, this may be a typo on your part, but the k param is referenced as K (wrong case).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change at the if condition

Change 1st if condition to

```
if ((A[i] != A[i+1]) && (A[i] + 1 != A[i+1]) {
    return false;
}
```

Change 2nd if condition to

```
if (A[0] != 1 || A[n-1] != K) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this change is enough
if (A[0] != 1 || A[n-1] != K)

Answer (score 0):

```
int  n = A.size(); // int is missing
```

Other than the ones pointed out above, the overall logic is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit overdone, but guaranteed to be correct:

```
bool algorithmc(vector<int>& A, int k)
{
    int n = A.size();
    //null checking
    if (n < k)
        return false;
    
    // easy checking
    if(A[0] != 1 || A[n-1] != k)
      return false;
    
    vector<int> flags(k + 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        // all data less than and equal to k
        if (A[i] <= k) 
            flags[A[i]] = 1;
        else
            return false;
        // check the input is valid
        if (A[i + 1] < A[i])
            return false;
    }
    //check the last one
    if (A[n - 1] <= k)
        flags[A[n - 1]] = 1;
    else
        return false;

    // this is to make sure all data in range 1..k appear.
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        if (!flags[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug is if given empty vector (no null check), and/or a vector starting with 0 will pass the test when it is supposed to fail. here is my solution

```html
bool algorithm(vector<int> &A, int k)
{
   int n = A.size();
   //if vector is size zero return false;
   if(n <=0)
   return false;
   
   bool vector_dont_have_one = A[0] != 1;
   bool vector_dont_have_k = A[n-1] != k;
   
   if(vector_dont_have_one || vector_dont_have_k)
   {
       return false;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
       bool is_not_sorted = A[i]+1 < A[i+1];
      if(is_not_sorted){
         return false;
      }
   }
  
  return true;
}
```